# D3.js Threshold encoding gradient based on angle not radius

Tags: d3.js, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I am trying to achieve gradient thresholding based on an angular position rather than radius.  I am including two examples.

**Example 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/TennisAiP/23x7bdq8/

```
  svg.append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "wlgradient")
      .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
      .attr("x1", x(1)).attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("x2", x(20)).attr("y2", 0)
    .selectAll("stop")
      .data([
        {offset: "0%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "5%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "5%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "10%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "10%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "15%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "15%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "20%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "20%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "30%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "30%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "55%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "55%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "70%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "70%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "85%", color: "limegreen"},
        {offset: "85%", color: "red"},
        {offset: "100%", color: "red"}
      ])
    .enter().append("stop")
      .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
      .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

[image]

The first example is based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3970883 but changes thresholding to the x axis to demonstrate what I wish to achieve for the second example where the gradient is currently changed based on radius thresholding.

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/TennisAiP/z79v4p9w/

```
   var grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient").data(data)
       .enter().append("radialGradient")
       .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
       .attr("cx", 0)
       .attr("cy", 0)
       .attr("r", "100%")
       .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "grad" + i; });

   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'red'; });
   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "15%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'red'; });
   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "15%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'limegreen'; });
   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "18%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'limegreen'; });
   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "18%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'red'; });
   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "22%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'red'; });
   grads.append("stop").attr("offset", "22%").style("stop-color", function(d, i) { return 'limegreen'; });
```

[image]

Imagine a radial graph such as the one above using d3.svg.line.radial() where the line could potentially run through all the colors of a color wheel, independent of the radius.

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I have seen that, but was hoping there was another way.